# Wake up your app from a local notification action - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, uilocalnotification

My app schedules a local notification with two actions on a specific time.
By the time it arrives on the phone (few hours later) my app is already in a suspended state and pressing any action button leads to nothing or simply crashes the app.

In documentation i've read that `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method works for handling such tasks and waking up the app from the suspended state, but i have no idea how to implement it properly for actions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didReceiveRemoteNotification is called when you receive a push notification via APNS.  You should be using a handler for didReceiveLocalNotification in your AppDelegate.